# Do I need to mud drywall before applying ship lap?

Tags: drywall

I am put up ship lap in my bathroom and replacing drywall. Covering and sealing drywall. Is it necessary with ship lap? It's in the bathroom.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Are you covering existing drywall with ship lap, or replacing the drywall with new drywall and covering THAT with ship lap?

Answer (score 2):

I would say best practice would be to at least seal the drywall with a primer so it does not absorb the moisture in the humid post shower air.

Code (may?) require the joints have at least a tape applied with a skim coat of mud for fire code. That is speculation on my part.

If the gaps in the ship lap will reveal the drywall you will want it a color of your choice.

Personally i would prime and paint it with a semigloss.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to do anything to the drywall. In fact you could even forego the drywall and just do the shiplap directly.

Since this is a bathroom be wary of the moisture and how it affects wood. I'd seal/paint the shiplap.

Comment: i am not sure of that in living spaces the interior walls require fire protection ship lap would not meet that code. Similar to what Alaska man is stating requiring a mud coat on the joints.

Comment: Fire code from my understanding is only between a garage and living space (above, next) and require 5/8 drywall. Unless the bathroom is next to a garage it can probably forego the drywall. But if it is, it will need a way to stay dry. Drywall behind it will just breed mold even if primed.